# How to remove a transparent line that appears between list items in XML Android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am linking image and text together to display in a fragment. Everything works just fine except for this transparent line that appears under each item. This line shows the layout of the activity which the fragment is called from. How can I make this fundraiser.xml take up all the screen, no matter how many items in my list and how to I get rid of that line after each item?
I have uploaded an image to better explain my problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/147It.png

This is my fundraiser.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="20px"
            android:src="@drawable/blai"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:dividerHeight="-8dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:text="@+id/label"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my fundraiserfragmen file

```
package com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.adapter.MobileArrayAdapter;

public class FundraiserFragment extends ListFragment {

static final String[] values = new String[] {"Landsbjörg", "Blái  Naglinn", "SÁÁ Álfurinn"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(getActivity(),values));
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long ID) {
    String value = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

This is my MobileArrayAdapter file

```
package com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.devnied.emvnfccard.R;

public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.fundraiser, R.id.label, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fundraiser, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);

    if (s.equals("Landsbjörg")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.landsbjorg);
    } else if (s.equals("Blái Naglinn")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blai);
    } else if (s.equals("SÁÁ Álfurinn")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.saa_alfurinn);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    return rowView;

}
}
```

Comment: `android:divider = "@null"` add this to your listview in XML

Comment: I don't have a listview, only textview and imageview in my XML. I tried this in both views and the line did not go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:divider = "@null"` as Skynet told in comment, or if you want to make it programmatically you should do:
`getListView().setDivider(null);` in `onActivityCreated()` method.

**Note :** didn't see other answer while making this

Comment: I had to make a new gridview which used the fundraiser.xml file. When I put the divider = null there it worked.

Answer (score 1):

use [setDividerHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDividerHeight(int))

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
    setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(getActivity(),values));
}
```